# how to grab geo-data location from gramfeed?

Tags: data-visualization, instagram-api

I'm kind of new to all the programming language, and i want to grab the geo-locations for academic research in purpose of visualization data.

There is any simple way for this? or simple tutorial how to do this? i need to extract the geo-locations from the map to csv\json\xls file

Comment: have you programmed with python? here's a python api wrapper: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram checkout location and geographies in the data retrieval section of the readme

Comment: there is any guide or tutorial how to use this wrapper?

Comment: gramfeed uses instagram APIs to add to map, just use the instagram API, it will return data in json format for photos, which may also have geo location information, not all photos will have geo-location.

Answer (score 0):

The readme here (https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) is a tutorial.

For example to authenticate with the API use:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
```

Then you could *locations* information as with these three queries:

```
api.location(location_id)
api.location_recent_media(count, max_id, location_id)*
api.location_search(q, count, lat, lng, foursquare_id, foursquare_v2_id)
```

The docs for the location "endpoint" of this API (https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/).

Essentially the above commands could send a request like:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

The Instagram API response would be:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "788029",
        "latitude": 48.858844300000001,
        "longitude": 2.2943506,
        "name": "Eiffel Tower, Paris"
    },
    {
        "id": "545331",
        "latitude": 48.858334059662262,
        "longitude": 2.2943401336669909,
        "name": "Restaurant 58 Tour Eiffel"
    },
    {
        "id": "421930",
        "latitude": 48.858325999999998,
        "longitude": 2.294505,
        "name": "American Library in Paris"
    }]
}
```

Python can certainly export this data into one of the file types you mentioned. Note that there is also some really nice plotting capabilities, take a look; (http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html). The benefit of the wrapper is that you can directly interact with the response data. It would be like a Python dict object.

Comment: api.location_search(q, count, lat, lng, foursquare_id, foursquare_v2_id)? what i should put there?
q-?
count-?

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/instagram/client.py